# Laravel 4 how do I keep checkbox checked after form is submitted

Tags: php, laravel-4

In part of my edit form I have check boxes. I can submit the form just fine, the values are stored in the database as comma separated values. So apple,microsoft etc. Which works fine but when I go back to the edit form the check boxes are not checked.  I tried to echo out checked if the following was met:

```
<input name="software[]" type="checkbox"  value="Ortho trac" <?php if(isset($_POST['software'])) echo "checked"; ?>> Ortho trac
```

But the above code doesn't work. I am not sure how to do it in laravel. **Also when I try to update the values the previous values in the database disappear**

**The view**

```
<div class="form-group mtop-20">

    <label for="temp_software_experience">Software Experience:</label><br>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" class="input-sm" value="Practiceworks"> Practiceworks
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Softdent"> Softdent
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Ortho trac" <?php if (isset($_POST['software'])) echo "checked"; ?>> Ortho trac
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Dentrix"> Dentrix
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Easy Dental"> Easy Dental
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input name="software[]" type="checkbox" value="Practiceworks"> Eaglesoft
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="temp_software_experience" value="Other"> Other
    </label>

</div><!-- end .form-group -->
```

**The Controller**

```
public function update($id)
{

    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
        'firstname' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'lastname' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'zipcode' => 'required|min:5|numeric',
        'temp_experience' => 'required|min:1|max:50|numeric',
        'temp_travel' =>   'required|numeric',
        'temp_hourly_rate' => 'required|numeric|min:10',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('user/profile/' . $id . '/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {


        $software_checked = Input::get('software');
        if(is_array($software_checked))
        {
            $implade_software = implode(',', $software_checked);
        }

        // store
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname      = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->zipcode = Input::get('zipcode');
        $user->temp_experience = Input::get('temp_experience');
        $user->temp_travel = Input::get('temp_travel');
        $user->temp_hourly_rate = Input::get('temp_hourly_rate');
        $user->temp_software_experience = $implade_software;
        $user->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated profile!!');
        return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you update you are redirecting afterwards thus clearing your `POST` data.

```
// redirect
Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated profile!!');
return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'');
```

To access this data you will need to fetch it from your method of storage (database in this case), not your `POST` data as it contains nothing.

So that conditional should be something like:

```
<?php if(!empty($user->software)) echo "checked"; ?>
```

*Note: You should be using `Input::get()` even within the view, no point in using `$_POST`.*

#### Edit from comments:

The reason you are losing the data is because you first need `explode()` the data before you perform the conditional check against it.

Say you select:

```
[x] Apple
[ ] Orange
[x] Banana
```

In your column it would look something like `apple,banana`.

When you perform a conditional check it looks similar to this:

```
if ('apple,banana' == 'apple') echo 'checked';
```

You need to be checking if the an element within that comma delimited list exists. So try exploding it first and then checking it. This should be a good starting point.

```
$software = explode(',', $user->temp_software_experience);
```

Then for each input:

```
if (in_array("Practiceworks", $software)) echo "checked";
```

Here's the documentation for [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array).

Hope that clears some things up.

Comment: This works great <?php if(!empty($user->temp_software_experience) && $user->temp_software_experience == "Practiceworks") echo "checked"; ?> It shows the checked boxes when I go back to the edit page. Is there anything I can do for when a user checks an additional skill because right now when I check another check box none of them are checked and the previous selected values are not in the database @FruityP

Comment: Thank You for the help its working now as expected. Hope you enjoy your holidays @FruityP